# vuejs3 reactivity of props object

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm very enthausiast about vuejs but the composition API made me get lost slightly on reactivity:

In a .vue child component a prop is passed (by another parent component), movies:

```
export default {
    props:{
        movies: Array
    },
    setup(props){}
```

.

Placing in the **setup** function body of this child component:

```
A) console.log("props: ",props) // Proxy {}
```

[above EXPECTED] above tells me that the props object is a reactive proxy object.

```
B) console.log("props.movies: ",props.movies); // Proxy {}
```

[above UNEXPECTED] above tells me that the props key 'movies' is a reactive proxy object as well, why? (thus why is not only the main props object reactive? Maybe I should just take this for granted *(and e.g. think of it as the result of a props = reactive(props) call)*
--> ANSWER: props is a **deep ** reactive object (thanks Michal Levý!)

```
C) let moviesLocal = props.movies ; // ERROR-> getting value from props in root scope of setup will cause the value to loose reactivity
```

[above UNEXPECTED] As props.movies is a reactive object, I'd assume that I can assign this to a local variable, and this local variable then also would become reactive. Why is this not the case (I get the error shown above)

```
D) let moviesLocal = ref(props.movies);
   moviesLocal.value[0].Title="CHANGED in child component";
```

[above UNEXPECTED]
I made a local copy in the child component (moviesLocal). This variable I made reactive (ref). Changing the value of the reactive moviesLocal also causes the 'movies' reactive object in the parent object to change, why is that ? *This even holds if I change D: let moviesLocal = ref(props.movies); to let moviesLocal = ref({...props.movies});*

Thanks a lot! Looking forward to understand this behaviour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Important part of understanding Vue reactivity is understanding JavaScript - specifically difference between [Value and Reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0). If you are not sure what I'm talking about, read the article carefully...

In following examples I will be using `props` object as it was created following way (in reality it is not created *exactly* like this but runtime behavior is very similar):

```js
const props = reactive({ movies: [], price: 100 })
```

```
B) console.log("props.movies: ",props.movies); // Proxy {}
```

> above tells me that the props key 'movies' is a reactive proxy object as well, why?

Because when Vue creates new reactive object (by wrapping existing object into a Proxy), that conversion is [**deep**](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) - it affects all nested properties (this behavior can be changed by using for example `markRaw` or `shallowRef`)

In terms of Value vs Reference the `props` is a variable holding a reference to a reactive proxy object. That object has a property `movies` which holds the reference to a reactive proxy of array (arrays are also technically Objects)

```
C) let moviesLocal = props.movies ; 
// ERROR-> getting value from props in root scope of setup will cause the value to loose reactivity
```

> As props.movies is a reactive object, I'd assume that I can assign this to a local variable, and this local variable then also would become reactive. Why is this not the case

Variables are not reactive. Only Objects can be reactive. In this case `moviesLocal` variable is assigned with reference to same reactive object as `props.movies` (`moviesLocal === props.movies` returns `true`). This object is **still reactive**.

Let's use our `moviesLocal` variable in the template to render some kind of list...

If for example parent mutates the array referenced by `props.movies` (adding new item with `push()`, assigning different value to `props.movies[0]` etc.) child will be notified about the change and its template will re-render.

So why the error? Where is the "loose reactivity" ? Problem is what happens when parent replaces the value of `props.movies` with different\new array. Our `moviesLocal` variable will still hold the reference to previous reactive array. Our **child component will still be reactive to changes (mutations) of that original array but lost the ability to react to changes of `props.movies` property.**

This is demonstrated in [this demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbiAgaW1wb3J0IHsgcmVmIH0gZnJvbSBcInZ1ZVwiXG4gaW1wb3J0IGNvbXAgZnJvbSAnLi9Db21wLnZ1ZSdcblxuIGNvbnN0IG1vdmllcyA9IHJlZihbXCJNYXRyaXhcIiwgXCJJUCBNYW5cIl0pXG4gXG4gY29uc3QgY291bnRlciA9IHJlZigxKVxuIGNvbnN0IG11dGF0ZSA9ICgpID0+IHsgbW92aWVzLnZhbHVlLnB1c2goYFN0YXIgV2FycyAke2NvdW50ZXIudmFsdWUrK31gKSB9XG4gY29uc3QgcmVwbGFjZSA9ICgpID0+IG1vdmllcy52YWx1ZSA9IFtcIk1hdHJpeFwiLCBcIklQIE1hblwiXVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPGgzPlxuICAgIENoaWxkIGNvbXBvbmVudCBpcyByZWFjdGluZyB0byBhcnJheSBtdXRhdGlvbi4gSXQgd2lsbCBzdG9wIHJlYWN0aW5nIGFzIHNvb24gYXMgeW91IHVzZSBSZXBsYWNlIDFzdCB0aW1lXG4gIDwvaDM+XG4gIDxidXR0b24gQGNsaWNrPVwibXV0YXRlXCI+XG4gICAgTXV0YXRlIChwdXNoKVxuICA8L2J1dHRvbj5cbiAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9XCJyZXBsYWNlXCI+XG4gICAgUmVwbGFjZVxuICA8L2J1dHRvbj5cbiAgPGNvbXAgOm1vdmllcz1cIm1vdmllc1wiPjwvY29tcD5cbiAgPHByZT57eyBtb3ZpZXMgfX08L3ByZT5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsIkNvbXAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbiAgaW1wb3J0IHsgd2F0Y2gsIGlzUmVmIH0gZnJvbSBcInZ1ZVwiXG4gIGNvbnN0IHByb3BzID0gZGVmaW5lUHJvcHMoe1xuICAgIG1vdmllczoge1xuICAgICAgdHlwZTogQXJyYXlcbiAgICB9XG4gIH0pXG4gIFxuICBjb25zdCBsb2NhbE1vdmllcyA9IHByb3BzLm1vdmllc1xuICB3YXRjaChsb2NhbE1vdmllcywgKHZhbCkgPT4gY29uc29sZS5sb2coSlNPTi5zdHJpbmdpZnkodmFsKSkpICBcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICAgPGRpdiB2LWZvcj1cIm0gaW4gbG9jYWxNb3ZpZXNcIj5cbiAgICAge3sgbSB9fVxuICA8L2Rpdj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+In0=)

The funny thing is that in the core, this behavior has nothing to do with Vue reactivity. It is just plain JS. Check this:

```js
const obj = {
  movies: ['Matrix']
}
const local = obj.movies
obj.movies = ['Avatar']
```

What is the value of `local` at this point ? Of course it is `['Matrix']`! `const local = obj.movies` is just value assignment. It does not somehow magically "link" the `local` variable with the value of `obj.movies` object property.

```
D) let moviesLocal = ref(props.movies);
moviesLocal.value[0].Title="CHANGED in child component";
```

> I made a local copy in the child component (moviesLocal). This variable I made reactive (ref).

Again, variables **are not reactive**. Objects they point to (reference) can be reactive. Array referenced by `props.movies` was already reactive proxy. You just created a `ref` which holds that same object

> Changing the value of the reactive moviesLocal also causes the 'movies' reactive object in the parent object to change, why is that ?

Because both point to (reference) same array (wrapped by Vue proxy) in the memory. Assign a new array to one of them and the this "link" will break...

Comment: Wow Michal, thanks a lot. Tomorrow I'll re and re-read your comment. I think I can follow but want to be able to fully understand!

Comment: and I do, thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Use `toRef` to maintain reactivity.

```
const moviesLocalRef = toRef(props, 'movies')
```

See https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref

The rule is that a `reactive` object child property must always be accessed from the root of the object. `a.b.c.d`. You cannot just `break off a piece and modify it`, because the act of resolving from the root is what allows Vue to track changes.

In your case, the internal property is the same, but Vue has lost the ability to track changes.

As a side note, you can also create a computed reference.

```
const moviesLocalRef = computed(()=>props.movies)
```

Whether you use a `computed ref` or `toRef`, you will need to access your property using `theRef.value` outside of templates.  As I state in conclusion, this is what allows Vue to maintain the reactivity.

## Conclusion

Here is how I have chosen to think about Vue3 reactivity.

The act of `dereferencing a property` from an object is what triggers the magic.

For a `reactive object`, you need to start with the `reactive object` and then `drill down` to your property of interest.  For a `ref`, you need to unbox the `value` from the `ref`.  Either way, there is always a `get` operation that triggers the internal mechanism and notifies Vue who is watching what.

This `drilling down` happens automatically in templates and watchers that are aware they received a reference, but not anywhere  else.

See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#how-vue-tracks-these-changes

Comment: Edit made it much better. But I have still problem with the part *because the act of resolving from the root is what allows Vue to track changes*. This is oversimplification imo. You can pass around value of `props.movies` (which is an array) and that array will still be reactive

Comment: `watch(props.movies)` will be triggered by array mutations but fails on `props.movies` change (this is of course not correct usage of `watch` with props - just technical demonstration). Check the demo in my answer.

Comment: Not true again. Conversion to reactive proxies was and always will be deep/recursive and [it is documented](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive).

Comment: Thanks! Also for the nice tip about mentioning the option to use computed :)!